# Indesign script: set background image behind a text with a certain paragraph style

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I was searching for a solution in Indesign to set a background image behind a text with a certain paragraph style. Unfortunately I did not find any yet.
So I thought maybe you can help me out with a script where you:

- assign a paragraph style (let's say "chapter_head")
- search for its encounter in the whole document.
- cut text of the found item and paste it with the same style(or a copy of the style) into a new textframe
- load a picture behind the textframe ("small-frame.ai")
- group, and paste it to the position where we cut the text out
- repeat with all found elements

Thanks in advance!
Edit:
here as requested a picture of what I am aiming at

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a couple screenshots to illustrate what do you have and what do you want to get. Implementation depends on it.

Comment: Added an illustration, I hope now it is a bit clearer.

Comment: I think it can be done. Not sure if anchored frames is a best solution. I'd propose to use simply inline pasted frames (grouped text frame + picture): https://imgur.com/QUDnBFW.png

Comment: yes, right inline pasted frames are probably better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
// find all headers with style 'header'
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = '^.+$';
app.findGrepPreferences.appliedParagraphStyle = 'header';
var headers = app.activeDocument.findGrep();

// store contents of the headers in the array 'contents'
var contents = [];
while (headers.length) contents.push(headers.shift().contents);

// replace all the headers with placeholder from clipboard
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = '~C';
app.activeDocument.changeGrep();

// change all '#placeholder#' with contents of the headers
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = '#placeholder#';
var placeholders = app.activeDocument.findGrep();
while (contents.length) placeholders.pop().contents = contents.pop();
```

The script finds all the paragraphs with style 'header', changes them with contents of clipboard (a group: image + text '#placeholder#'), then finds and changes all the texts '#placeholder#' with contents of the headers.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: yes, thank you, that's it!!! at first it did not work, because it did not find my paragraph style, because it was grouped in a folder, but after changing it, everything went fine. THank you again!

Comment: Did you move the style from the folder?

Comment: yes, I have moved it to the root folder and then it worked.

Comment: Btw, I have no ready solution how it could handle styles within folders. Probably there should be a style name like 'folder/style_name' or something like that. It's need to google.